# Present tense after past tense in long reported speech

Tags: reported-speech

Is it correct to use present tense clause in reported speech once we are done using past tense clause?

> The CJI said since the Places of Worship Act **was** in operation, it would be open for parties concerned to point out its provisions to courts where such proceedings **are** pending and seek stay.

Comment: I don't see why not, if it's a past comment about a current situation.

Comment: Please [cite the source of quoted text](https://ell.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1084/so-you-found-a-sentence-or-phrase-why-you-should-cite-your-source).

Comment: You can use the present tense following "said" if the thing being described is still true, e.g. "He said Paris is the capital of France." Or you can use the past. (This question comes up a lot.)

Comment: Why not use "were" instead of "are"?